# Grouping multiple items together after a ngFor

Tags: angular

Currently I have a ng-template that outputs items from an array. I am have trouble trying to group the `key_id` and `key_name` together as a set

i.e. ( **key_id = 1, key_name = hello1** ) , ( **key_id = 2, key_name = hello2** )... Now when I pass the values via `updateDate` the output should be **hello1:1, hello2:2**

```
<ng-template ngFor let-key [ngForOf]="item['data']['keys']">

    <a class="text-success" title="Edit Menu" 
    (click)="updateData(item['data']['title'],
    item['data']['url'],key['tag_id'],key['key_name'],false)">

        <i class="text-success fa fa-edit toogleIcon"></i>

    </a>

</ng-template>
```

**the JSON**

```
"data": [
{
"data": {
"id": "1",
"title": "Location",
"url": "location",
"keys": [
{
"key_id": "1",
"key_name": "DefaultLine"
},
{
"key_id": "4",
"key_name": "Mainline"
}
```

**TS for UpdateData**

```
private updateData(title: any, url: any, key_id: any, key_name: any, flag: boolean) {
  console.log('title=>', title);
  console.log('url=>', url);
  console.log('key_name=>', key_name);
  console.log('key_id=>', key_id);
  this.title = title;
  url === null ? this.url = "" : this.url = url;
  key_id === null ? this.key_id = "" : this.key_id = key_id;
  key_name === null ? this.key_name = "" : this.key_name = key_name;
}
```

Comment: Though the question relates to a template and data, we're missing `updateData`.

Comment: @stealththeninja thanks, i've added that to my question

Answer (score 2):

In the `updateData` function call in the `a` element, the third parameter looks for the `tag_id` property. From what I can make of your JSON, it should be looking for the `key_id` parameter. Maybe that's it?